# Callback functions with external functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, callback

In my plugin I handle animations externally,and they are fired only in some events.

ex:

```
var animateToLeft = function() {
    $elements.animate({
        marginLeft: '+=' + 300,
        marginRight: '-=' + 300
    });
},
    animateToRight = function() {
        $elements.animate({
            marginLeft: '-=' + 300,
            marginRight: '+=' + 300
        });
    };
```

Later in my plugin I have to check if an option is true or false and then apply the animations:

```
if( true === options ) {
    $button.click( animateToRight );
} else {
    $button.click( animateToLeft );
}
```

Thus far the code works just fine. but **I need to add two more callback functions according to the if-else statement**

```
var callback1 = function() {
    //do something
},
    callback2 = function() {
    //do something else
    }
```

**I cannot add callback functions to the animations directly** I need to add them during the **if-else statement**. I tried this way but it didn't worked:

```
if( true === options ) {
    $button.click( animateToRight, function() {
        $body.bind( callback1 );
    });
} else {
    $button.click( animateToLeft, function() {
        $body.bind( callback2 );
    });
}
```

How can I add those callbacks? Is there a simpler way maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the callback to the animate function which will be called once the animation is complete.

```
// Allow animate functions to be passed a callback
var animateToLeft = function (callback)
{
    $elements.animate({
        marginLeft: '+=' + 300,
        marginRight: '-=' + 300
    }, callback);
},
animateToRight = function (callback)
{
    $elements.animate({
        marginLeft: '-=' + 300,
        marginRight: '+=' + 300
    }, callback);
};

var callback1 = function(){};
var callback2 = function(){};

if( true === options )
{
    $button.on('click', function()
    {
        // when button is clicked call animate with the callback.
        animateToRight(callback1)
    });
} 
else
{
    $button.on('click', function()
    {
        animateToRight(callback2)
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zMGft/1/)